# how to copy a file to the desktop

Tags: copy

I am just starting out but I am running into issues copying different files. Ultimately I am trying to copy file3.txt to the desktop. I started off by creating a directory and the file3.txt.

`cd Desktop`

`mkdir Classes`

`mkdir Classes/NOS110`

`mkdir Classes/NOS110/Handouts`

`mkdir Classes/NOS110/Handouts/file3.txt`

`cd` (to get back to home directory)

`ls -a Desktop/Classes/NOS110` (to list the contents of the NOS110 directory)

`cp file3.txt Desktop` (it keeps saying it does not exist) 
I've tried different ways to get it to copy over and im stuck [what I have tried in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skfmt.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You must give an unambiguous path to the file - otherwise the system can only assume that it's in the *current* directory.

Since you used `cd` to return to your home directory, that would be

```
cp -r Desktop/Classes/NOS110/Handouts/file3.txt Desktop/
```

The `-r` is necessary since despite its name, `file3.txt` is a directory (you created it using `mkdir` - perhaps you should have used `touch`?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Edit : When you are in the directory which the folder which the file is in) :

```
cp file3.txt ~/Desktop
```